# EXT4 slower performance successive writes

Tags: io, fwrite, ext4

I'm working with a C program that does a bunch of things but in some part it writes a whole HDD with multiple calls to fwrite on a single file with a fixed size.

The calls are something like this:

```
    fwrite(some_memory,size_element,total_elements,file);
```

When I measure the wall time of this calls each call takes a bit longer than the previous one. So for example, if want to write in chunks of 900MB of data, the first call (with empty disk) ends within 7 seconds but the last ones takes somewhere between 10~11 secs (with the disk almost at full capacity).

Is this an expected behavior? Is there any way of getting consistent write times independently of disk current capacity? 
I'm using an EXT4 wd green 2TB volume.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say this is to be expected as your early calls are most likely satisfied by the kernel's writeback cache and thus returning slightly quicker because at the time fwrite returns not all the data has reached the disk yet. However I don't know how much memory your system has compared to the 900MBytes of data you're trying to write so this is a guess...

If the kernel's cache becomes full (e.g. because the disk can't keep up) then your userspace program is made to block until it is sufficiently empty and able to accept a bit more data leaky bucket style. Only once all data has gone in to the cache can the fwrite complete. However at that point you are likely doing another fwrite call that tops the cache up again and your subsequent call is forced to wait a bit longer because the cache has not been fully emptied. I'd imagine you would reach a fixed point though...

To see if caches really were behind the behaviour you could issue an fsync after each fwrite (destroying your performance) and take the time from the fwrite submission to fsync completion and see if the variance was so large.

Another thing you could do that might help is to preallocate the full size of the file up front so that the filesystem isn't forced to keep regrowing it as new data is appended to the end (this should cut down on metadata operations and fight fragmentation too).

The dirty_* knobs in https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/sysctl/vm.txt are also likely comming in to play given the large amounts of data you are writing.